# How many literals are there in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, literals, template-literals

I was working on some project involving regex and suddenly encountered a `regex literal` which looks like this:

```
/ab+c/g
```

I know that in programming languages there are some fixed list of possible literals, like in C language `integer`, `float` etc.

Then I searched for the list of literals supported in javascript but could not found satisfactory answer.

I experimented with node prompt and got following interesting results:

```
> typeof /ab+c/g
'object'
> str = 'xyz'
'xyz'
> typeof `abc ${str}`
'string'
> typeof function f(x, y) {
... return x + y;
... }
'function'
> typeof {
... 'a': 'b'
... }
'object'
```

This proves that

- `regex literal` is essentially `object literal`
- `template literal` is essentially `string literal`
- `function literal` is `function literal`
- `javascript object literal` is `object literal`

Even though last one is okay and defined in many places but it doesn't make sense to me that regex literal is still `object literal`.

Where is it written? How can I find out list of possible literals in javascript?

Comment: A regex literal results in an object instance. Because virtually everything is an object in Javascript. That does not make a regex literal an object *literal*.

Comment: No, a regex literal is not “essentially an object literal”. `RegExp`s are objects, but they have nearly no overlap with object literals in how they’re used.

Comment: So regex literal is not a literal at all?

Comment: A regex literal is definitely a literal, but an “object literal” means `{foo: 'bar', …}`.

Comment: @Kartoos, that depends on what you mean by "literal."  The language defines *RegularExpressionLiteral* as a kind of token, but when a `/./` expression is encountered it creates a new value each time, so `/./ !== /./`.  Unlike other languages, regular expressions specified in literal form are not collected in a literal pool.

Comment: A *literal* is what *literally* appears typed in the source code. The *value* that this results in is something else. A regex literal results in a `RegExp` object. An object literal results in an object. A literal doesn't result in another literal.

Comment: I am more confused now as to what a literal should mean! In C language world, it is a constant and there are just fixed number of possible types of those constants which can be stored in some variable with datatype

Comment: I don't know the full list, but a few more are: number literals (several formats - scientific notation, octal, hexadecimal, decimal - includes weird ones like NaN, Infinity), boolean literals, undefined literals, null literals. To expand on the list, I would look up all the types then see which have literals. This is not so straightforward because you might consider an arrow function, or normal function to be a function literal, but the spec considers functions to be a kind of object, and not their own type.

Comment: @Kartoos, I wouldn't get too hung up on what is or isn't a literal.  ["Syntactic sugar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) is a broader term that captures what seems to concern you, and is more widely used in language design debates in my experience.  For example: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aesdiscuss.org+"syntactic+sugar"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at appendix A of [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-grammar-summary) and you'll find definitions of *StringLiteral*, etc.  Btw, the spec uses *FunctionExpression*, not *FunctionLiteral*.

Also relevant is [11.8 Literals](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar-literals).  Thereunder are

- *NullLiteral* ::== `null`
- *BooleanLiteral* ::== `true` | `false`
- *NumberLiteral*
- *RegularExpressionLiteral*
- *StringLiteral*
- *TemplateLiteral* components.

Notably, `undefined` is not a literal.

As that section makes clear, "literal" refers to abbreviated syntax, and does not relate to any object/primitive distinction.

Elsewhere in the text (chapter 12 *PrimaryExpression*) you'll see terms like *ObjectLiteral* and *ArrayLiteral* but those are also referred to as *{Object,Array}Initializer*s.

Comment: Can i say that some literals are used for creating objects as in ArrayLiteral while some are not?

Comment: OR ObjectLiteral and ArrayLiteral are not literals at all?

Comment: @Kartoos, Depends how you define terms.

If by "literal" you mean abbreviated syntax for specifying a value, then they're literals.  If you define "literal" as a simple kind of expression, then *ObjectInitializer*s and *TemplateString*s are not literal because they can embed arbitrarily complicated expressions.

I don't know of a definition that language designers broadly agree upon; language debates I've been part of tend to focus on whether "syntactic sugar" would help or hurt instead of whether something is or isn't a literal.

Comment: I am accepting your answer since you have given me official link to documentation regarding these concepts although it is still interesting to see that even language designers are not strict about its definition either. I will just consider whatever is there in the documentation as the official definition.

Answer (score 1):

You might avoid thinking too hard about `typeof` results. While occasionally useful for determining what kind of value a variable holds, it's not really same as the object **type** in the sense you know it in C or OOP languages.

Observe:

```
typeof (()=>{})
> "function"
(()=>{}) instanceof Object
> true
```

Also:

```
typeof ""
> "string"
typeof new String("")
> "object"
"" instanceof String
> false
```

To answer your main question, there are the following literals:

- `()=>{}` lambda literal

  - `typeof ()=>{} == "function"`
- `function() {}` function literal

  - `typeof function() {} == "function"`
- `""` string literal

  - `typeof "" == "string"`
- ``` `` ``` string template literal

  - ``` typeof `` == "string" ```
- `42` number literal

  - `typeof 42 == "number"`
- `/x/` RegExp literal

  - `typeof /x/ == "object"`
- `[]` array literal

  - `typeof [] == "object"`
- `false` boolean literal

  - `typeof false == "boolean"`
- `null` literal for null object, note that

  - `typeof null == "object"`
- `{}` and object literal

  - `typeof {} == "object"`

Of all those, only string literals and number literals have `value instanceof Object == false`. The rest is all instance of object.

The caveats in `typeof` and `instanceof` are important when writing code that may receive various types. Generally `typeof` logic is:

- Is it a raw string (not `new String`)?
      - return "string"
- Is it a raw number?
      - return "number"
- Is it raw boolean?
      - return "boolean"
- Is it `undefined` (note that `null` is not undefined!)
      - return "undefined"
- Is it a function?
      - return "function"
- Otherwise return "object"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So typeof is not the correct way to evaluate literals but can be used for variables?

Comment: Unless you do crazy things like the mentioned `new String()`, you may use `typeof` to distinguish between the basic types and objects. For objects, you then want to use `instanceof` to distinguish each. It's best to write the code as if it was hard typed like C, then you don't have to worry so much. But one typical use of typeof is a function that may accept a single string or an array of strings.

Comment: @Kartoos You're never evaluating *literals*, ever. You can't. The *literal* is parsed and compiled into a runtime object. You can only ever inspect the runtime object that resulted from the literal.

Comment: @deceze So your point is literals ultimately convert into objects   at runtime? like 1.2f in C language will convert to floating datatype object ultimately Right?

Comment: @Kartoos Yes, exactly.